# How to initialize std::stop_callback?

Tags: c++, c++20

What is the right way to initialize `std::stop_callback` in the code below?

```
class watch_dog
{
public:

    watch_dog(std::stop_token token) :
        m_token(token),
        m_callback(m_token, std::bind(&watch_dog::callback_proc, this))
    {
    }

private:

    void callback_proc()
    {
        std::cout << "an operation has completed." << std::endl;
    }

    std::stop_token m_token;

    std::stop_callback m_callback;
};
```

Is there a way in C++ to register the callback without using `std::stop_callback` class?

How do I determine the type of my `std::bind` to declare `m_callback` as

```
std::stop_callback<type of my std::bind> m_callback;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stop_callback` is not type-erased; it is a template that stores the exact type of the callable object you want to call. If you want to erase the stored type, then the callable it stores needs to do that erasure. Like `std::function`:

```
std::stop_callback<std::function<void()>> m_callback;
```

That should be able to store the result of `std::bind`.

You can even make a convenient template alias:

```
template<typename Func>
using stop_callback_func = std::stop_callback<std::function<Func>>;

...

stop_callback_func<void()> m_callback;
```

Comment: I want it to be exactly `std::stop_callback<type of my std::bind>`

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky: You could do some `decltype` shenanigans, but there's really no reason to.

Comment: Is not `std::stop_callback<type of my std::bind>` better than `std::stop_callback<std::function>`?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky: ... in what way would it be "better"? This is a callback that will be called exactly *one time*: when a stop is requested. So any cost of type erasure is irrelevant to the overall performance of your program. I prefer code that lacks redundant information, and the `decltype` gymnastics would definitely be redundant information that can easily get out of sync.